# Connectivity problems with 2 switches

Tags: connection, switch

I have connected two switches (`SW1` and `SW2`) to each other using an Ethernet cable.

When I connect `SW1` with the router (using an Ethernet cable), none of the ports on either switch have connectivity to the Internet.

When I connect `SW2` with the router, all ports on both switches have connectivity to the Internet.

`SW1`: 1000 TP-link

`SW2`: 100 TP-link

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you get link lights on both the switch and the router when you connect SW1 to the router?  Is it the same for any port on SW1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some while, but I found the solution!

The problem was in the Ethernet cable. Two of the inside cables were cut. I read that the 100 switch uses only 4 of the 8 wires in the Ethernet cable, while the 1000 uses them all. That's why when I was connecting SW2 with the router, all ports on both switches had connectivity to the Internet.